# Trying to check the username and password within my json file to see if a student can log in

Tags: java, json, swing

Here is the code that I have so far. I have created the whole login screen and login button. Right now I have it so that the button disappears when it's pressed but I want to be able to check the JSON file to confirm the username and password and then move to the next screen.

Login Screen:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class LoginPage extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -337449186297669567L;
    private JLabel user_label = new JLabel("Username: ");
    private JLabel password_label = new JLabel("Password: ");
    private JLabel screenName = new JLabel("Login",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private JTextField username = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField password = new JTextField(10);
    private JButton login, cancel;
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private String hidden = "login";
    
    public LoginPage() {
        System.out.println("Creating the label panel");
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        add(screenName);
        add(user_label);
        add(username);
        add(password_label);
        add(password);
        login = new JButton("LOGIN");
        setVisible(true);
        addToggleListener();
      initialize();
      //setVisible(true);
    }
public void initialize(){
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        add(buttonPanel);
        c.weightx = 0.6;
        c.weighty = 0.6;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 50, 10, 20);

        login.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));

        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST;
        buttonPanel.add(login,c);
    }
    public void setText(String s) {
        screenName.setText(s);
    }

    public boolean isLabelVisible() {
        return screenName.isVisible();
    }

    public void setLabelVisibility(boolean value) {
        screenName.setVisible(value);
    }
    
    
    public void addToggleListener(ActionListener al){
        login.addActionListener(al);
    }

    public void addToggleListener() {
      login.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       if(hidden.equals("login")){
                 login.setVisible(false);
              } else {
                  login.setVisible(true);
              }
          }
    });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Main which contains the code for the json file:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import javax.enterprise.util.TypeLiteral;

import javax.json.bind.Jsonb;
import javax.json.bind.JsonbBuilder;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AppFrame frame = new AppFrame();
        LoginPage lp = new LoginPage();
        ToggleListener tl = new ToggleListener(lp);

        lp.addToggleListener(tl);

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(lp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
        addAnisa(studentList);
        Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();
        String jsonStudent = jsonb.toJson(studentList);
        java.lang.reflect.Type t = new TypeLiteral<List<Student>>(){}.getType();
        List<Student> l2 = jsonb.fromJson(jsonStudent, t);
        String homeDirectory = System.getProperty("user.home");
        Path p = Paths.get(homeDirectory + "/NetBeansProjects");
        if(!Files.exists(p)){
            File f = new File(homeDirectory + "/NetBeansProjects");
            if(!f.mkdir()){
                System.out.println("Nope");
            }
        }   
        String s = homeDirectory + "/NetBeansProjects/studentInfo.json";
        p = Paths.get(s);
        File f2 = new File(s); 
        try{
            System.out.println("writing out file");
            System.out.println(f2.getAbsoluteFile());
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f2.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw); 
            bw.write(jsonStudent);
            bw.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
       
       
    }
    private static void addAnisa(List<Student> list){
        Student s = new Student();
        
        s.setFirstName("Anisa");
        s.setLastName("Callis");
        List<LoginInfo> loginInfo = new ArrayList<>();
        LoginInfo LI = new LoginInfo();
        LI.setUsername("amc123");
        LI.setPassword("demo2021");
        loginInfo.add(LI);
        s.setLoginInfo(loginInfo);
        list.add(s);
        
    }

}
```

The frame:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class AppFrame extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -337449186297669567L;

    public AppFrame(){
        setTitle("Plan & Earn");
        setSize(400, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Student LoginInfo:

```
public class LoginInfo {
    String username;
    String password;
    public LoginInfo(){
        
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    
}
```

Student info for the json file:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Student {
     String firstName; 
     String lastName; 
    private List<LoginInfo> loginInfo;
    
    
    
    public Student(){
    
}

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public List<LoginInfo> getLoginInfo() {
        return loginInfo;
    }

    public void setLoginInfo(List<LoginInfo> loginInfo) {
        this.loginInfo = loginInfo;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Student{" + "firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", Login Info=" + loginInfo + '}';
    }
    
}
```

Comment: So you're heading in the basic right direction.  You're going to need to clean up the handling of the student data.  The intention is to pass some kind "authenticator" to `LoginPage`, so when you press the login button, you can delegate the actually workflow to it.  If it succeeds, you need to then generate some kind of event to another listener which can deal with the "success" workflow and move the user on into the application

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you're kind of heading in the right direction.  Some things you're going to want to consider are:

1. Providing a self contained manager/service for managing the students.  This would be responsible for loading, updating and generally manager the students, preferably in some way which decoupled the physical "how" away from the rest of the app (no one cares that it's backed by a JSON file, they only care about "doing stuff")
2. Providing some kind of authentication workflow which is independent of the UI.  The `LoginPage`s responsibility is about collecting information from the user.  It's not responsible for the underlying workflow of "how" a user is authenticated
3. Providing some kind of callback from the `LoginPage` to inform interested parties that a student has logged in

The main goal is to reduce the coupling of the system (the amount that any one part of the system relies on another part).  When designing a solution, you want to be always thinking about how hard it would be to modify any one part of the solution and how much impact that might have on other parts of the system.

For example, if you decided to move the student management to a SQL database or a web service, what impact would that have on other parts your solution.  If you find yourself having to make major modifications to other parts of the solution, then it's tightly coupled, which isn't a good thing.

There are number of ways you can approach these issues, but the following are some basic design principles you should keep in mind:

- [Delegation Pattern](http://best-practice-software-engineering.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/patterns/delegation.html)
- [Dependency Injection](http://best-practice-software-engineering.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/patterns/dependency_injection.html)
- [Observer](http://best-practice-software-engineering.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/patterns/observer.html)

There's also discussions over how much information any part of the system really needs, for example, the `LoginPage` doesn't really need access to the student database, that's not it's responsibility, so we should "hide" the details from it and only provide it with the details it really needs to  do its job.

This is where you will find the concept of "code to interface" powerful

- [Smarter Java development](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2076468/smarter-java-development.html)
- [OOP Good Practices: Coding to the interface](https://medium.com/javarevisited/oop-good-practices-coding-to-the-interface-baea84fd60d3)
- And many more, just Google around

Okay, but how does that help?  Well a lot actually.

Let's start back at the `LoginPage`.  It wants to ...

- Get the user's login credentials from the user
- Validate the credentials against the system
- Notify some interested party when the authentication is success

To start with, we need some way to authenticate the user which is decoupled from the physical implementation (ie "delegate")...

```
public interface Authenticator {
    public Student authenticate(String userName, char[] password);
}
```

I know, you're underwhelmed, but this is really very powerful.  This provides the `LoginPage` with the ability to pass the credentials into some system and have it either return a `Student` or `null` based on it's own internal needs.  `LoginPage` doesn't care.  So we could implement a bunch of different workflows and `LoginPage` won't ever change, win

Next, we need someway for `LoginPage` to notify interested parties when the authentication is success (ie an "observer)...

```
public class LoginPage extends JPanel {

    public static interface LoginListener {
        public void loginWasSucessful(LoginPage source, Student student);
    }
```

Now, I've defined this as a inner `interface` to `LoginPage`, this is mostly done this way because `LoginListener` will only ever be used within a context of `LoginPage`, but you can declare it as seperate `interface` in it's own file if you want, doesn't matter.  The point is, this defines a contract to which interested parties can be notified of "successful logins"

Now, we need to start putting it together.

First, I updated your `LoginPage`.  I've modified the constructor to accept an instance of `Authenticator` and `LoginListener`...

```
public class LoginPage extends JPanel {

    public static interface LoginListener {
        public void loginWasSucessful(LoginPage source, Student student);
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -337449186297669567L;
    private JLabel user_label = new JLabel("Username: ");
    private JLabel password_label = new JLabel("Password: ");
    private JLabel screenName = new JLabel("Login", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private JTextField username = new JTextField(10);
    private JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField(10);
    private JButton login, cancel;
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private String hidden = "login";

    private Authenticator authenticator;
    private LoginListener loginListener;

    public LoginPage(Authenticator authenticator, LoginListener loginListener) {
        this.authenticator = authenticator;
        this.loginListener = loginListener;
        
        setBorder(new CompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(16, 16, 16, 16), BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder()));
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        add(screenName, gbc);

        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;

        add(user_label, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(password_label, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;

        add(username, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(password, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        login = new JButton("LOGIN");
        add(login, gbc);

        login.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                login.setEnabled(false);
                Student student = authenticator.authenticate(username.getText(), password.getPassword());
                if (student != null) {
                    loginListener.loginWasSucessful(LoginPage.this, student);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LoginPage.this, "Authentication failed", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                login.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The interesting part is here at the end, where we handle the `ActionEvent` for `login`

Next, we need someway to actually authenticate the user, for this, I wrote a super simple "authenticator"

```
public class DefaultAuthenticator implements Authenticator {

    private List<Student> students;

    public DefaultAuthenticator(List<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }

    @Override
    public Student authenticate(String userName, char[] password) {
        for (Student student : students) {
            for (LoginInfo loginInfo : student.loginInfo) {
                if (userName.equals(loginInfo.getUsername()) && Arrays.equals(loginInfo.getPassword().toCharArray(), password)) {
                    return student;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

This is for test purposes.  When you build your "student manager", I'd be the tempted to either `implement` `Authenticator` directly or pass it (inject it) to the above implementation, what ever seems most appropriate to you at the time.

The next part is to test it!  For this, I built a simple `Student` and `LoginInfo` which was passed into the `DefaultAuthenticator`.  This then got passed to my main panel, which was responsible for setting up the primary UI...

```
public Test() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Load student information, maybe through some kind
            // of student service

            LoginInfo loginInfo = new LoginInfo("test", "1234");
            List<LoginInfo> loginList = new ArrayList<>();
            loginList.add(loginInfo);
            Student student = new Student();
            student.setLoginInfo(loginList);

            List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
            students.add(student);

            Authenticator authenticator = new DefaultAuthenticator(students);

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.add(new TestPane(authenticator));
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private CardLayout cardLayout;

    public TestPane(Authenticator authenticator) {
        cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        setLayout(cardLayout);
        LoginPage login = new LoginPage(authenticator, new LoginPage.LoginListener() {
            @Override
            public void loginWasSucessful(LoginPage source, Student student) {
                cardLayout.show(TestPane.this, "welcome");
            }
        });

        add(login, "login");
        add(new JLabel("Welcome", JLabel.CENTER), "welcome");
    }

}
```

The interesting part here is the handling of the successful login.  While all I'm doing here flip the UI over to show the "welcome" label, you can see that it's all decoupled and divorced from each other.

I don't care how the authentication works or how/when I get notified of the successful login, only that it can happen

## Runnable example

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Load student information, maybe through some kind
                // of student service

                LoginInfo loginInfo = new LoginInfo("test", "1234");
                List<LoginInfo> loginList = new ArrayList<>();
                loginList.add(loginInfo);
                Student student = new Student();
                student.setLoginInfo(loginList);

                List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
                students.add(student);

                Authenticator authenticator = new DefaultAuthenticator(students);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane(authenticator));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private CardLayout cardLayout;

        public TestPane(Authenticator authenticator) {
            cardLayout = new CardLayout();
            setLayout(cardLayout);
            LoginPage login = new LoginPage(authenticator, new LoginPage.LoginListener() {
                @Override
                public void loginWasSucessful(LoginPage source, Student student) {
                    cardLayout.show(TestPane.this, "welcome");
                }
            });

            add(login, "login");
            add(new JLabel("Welcome", JLabel.CENTER), "welcome");
        }

    }

    public interface Authenticator {
        public Student authenticate(String userName, char[] password);
    }

    public class DefaultAuthenticator implements Authenticator {

        private List<Student> students;

        public DefaultAuthenticator(List<Student> students) {
            this.students = students;
        }

        @Override
        public Student authenticate(String userName, char[] password) {
            for (Student student : students) {
                for (LoginInfo loginInfo : student.loginInfo) {
                    if (userName.equals(loginInfo.getUsername()) && Arrays.equals(loginInfo.getPassword().toCharArray(), password)) {
                        return student;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

    public class LoginPage extends JPanel {

        public static interface LoginListener {
            public void loginWasSucessful(LoginPage source, Student student);
        }

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -337449186297669567L;
        private JLabel user_label = new JLabel("Username: ");
        private JLabel password_label = new JLabel("Password: ");
        private JLabel screenName = new JLabel("Login", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        private JTextField username = new JTextField(10);
        private JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField(10);
        private JButton login, cancel;
        private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        private String hidden = "login";

        private Authenticator authenticator;
        private LoginListener loginListener;

        public LoginPage(Authenticator authenticator, LoginListener loginListener) {
            this.authenticator = authenticator;
            this.loginListener = loginListener;

            setBorder(new CompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(16, 16, 16, 16), BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder()));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(screenName, gbc);

            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;

            add(user_label, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(password_label, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;

            add(username, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(password, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            login = new JButton("LOGIN");
            add(login, gbc);

            login.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    login.setEnabled(false);
                    Student student = authenticator.authenticate(username.getText(), password.getPassword());
                    if (student != null) {
                        loginListener.loginWasSucessful(LoginPage.this, student);
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LoginPage.this, "Authentication failed", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                    login.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public class LoginInfo {

        String username;
        String password;

        public LoginInfo(String username, String password) {
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

    }

    public class Student {

        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        private List<LoginInfo> loginInfo;

        public Student() {

        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public List<LoginInfo> getLoginInfo() {
            return loginInfo;
        }

        public void setLoginInfo(List<LoginInfo> loginInfo) {
            this.loginInfo = loginInfo;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Student{" + "firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", Login Info=" + loginInfo + '}';
        }

    }
}
```

### Caveat

I have NOT, deliberately, merged your "student management" workflow with my example.  All I've done here is present a means by which you can build a workflow, connecting the authentication work (delegation) to the "what happens next" (observer) workflows.

You will need to build your solution in and around these concepts.

> But why (did you do that)?!

Because, giving you a "copy and paste" solution doesn't help you.  You need to be able to see your problem and design a solution around it using these design principles (there's a reason why they are bases of software engineering).

You have a runnable example which demonstrates the basic idea(s), now, you need to build your solution to around them and try and learn and understand them.